# Kendo template button ng-click not working

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Kendo ng -click button in the template does not work.Help us!

```
<div ng-controller="RiskProcessController">
   <script id="link-template" type="text/kendo-templ">  
        <button id="nextButton" class="btn btn-primary newButton" ng-click="Test()"> Click</button>
     </script>
 </div>
```

Angular Controller

```
manageApp.controller("RiskProcessController", ['$scope', '$http', '$uibModal',  function ($scope, $http, $uibModal, riskServices) {
   $("#Risks").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: dataSource,
        detailTemplate: kendo.template($("#link-template").html()),
        detailInit: detailInit,
        columns: []
     }
    $scope.Test = function(){
     console.log("test");
    }
}]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are initialising the KendoGrid using the jQuery syntax, which is NOT recommended, and will cause you issues.

Instead why not use the Angular/Kendo directives that are available from Kendo?

Please read documentation here on how to do so: http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/angular

If you do this, then you can do something like;

```
<div kendo-grid k-options="gridOptions" ng-controller="RiskProcessController">
    // grid code
</div>

manageApp.controller("RiskProcessController", ['$scope', '$http', '$uibModal',  function ($scope, $http, $uibModal, riskServices) {

    $scope.mainGridOptions = {
        dataSource: {},
        sortable: true,
        pageable: true,
        dataBound: function() {
            columns: []
        };
    }
}]);
```